# Graphic method for solution to partial differential equations

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm studying partial differential equations from pinchover and rubstein book called An introduction to partial differential equations and o'neil book called beginning to partial differential equations. I'm stuck in the part when they talk about the graphic method for solution to wave equations with the concept of characteristic curves:[image: enter image description he]

Someone have any idea why the support of backward wave is $[-1,\infty)$? In some part this author say that the support is where the solution is no zero, but if we take -1, the solution is 0 with this definition of the solution.

For other side, we have the graphical method but with characteristic cuadrilaterals. We can see this in O'neil book.

[image]

[image]

[image]

We can see here that he forms the cuadrilateral with respect to point P in the second region, because in the first region the solution is just general d'alambert formula ( the region 1 is precisely the characteristic triangule). But my problem here is that i was not able to find all sides of the cuadrilateral and the vertices that are very important to find the solution of the wave equation in this point using this formula:
[image]
I'll apreciate every suggestion about two questions, material (honestly, i dont find anything about this topic in another bibiliography)